# Check if iframe has specific id using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to call another function inside am iFrame like this:

```
function globalFunc(value) {
    //select and add ID to the iFrame
    const preloading_iFrame = $("iframe[src*='http://127.0.0.1:8887/Components/preloading/index.html']");
    preloading_iFrame.attr("id","preloadingID");
    // call iframe's function
    document.getElementById('preloadingID').contentWindow.iframeFunc(value);
}
```

Since I want to execute the `globalFunc` multiple times, I was wondering if we can bypass adding `id` to the iframe after the first time it has been added.

Something like check if iframe has the `preloadingID` as the `id` then don't add it again!

Is there any solution?

Comment: `if (preloading_iFrame.attr("id") != "preloadingID")`

Comment: Prepare an answer and it would be accepted...

Comment: But why bother? Checking the ID is as much work as changing the ID.

Comment: Are you sure you even need an ID? You already have a reference to the element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210764/discussion-between-foxer-and-barmar).

Comment: you mean this?: `preloading_iFrame.contentWindow.progressBar(value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to add the ID. You have a reference to the element already, just use that.

```
function globalFunc(value) {
    //select and add ID to the iFrame
    const preloading_iFrame = $("iframe[src*='http://127.0.0.1:8887/Components/preloading/index.html']");
    // call iframe's function
    preloading_iFrame[0].contentWindow.iframeFunc(value);
}
```

Indexing a jQuery collection returns the corresponding DOM elements.